# Removing 1 backslash from String (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backslash

I've got html text by parsing other site.
I've got this code:

```
"<div class=\"asset-body\"><div class=\"user-icon\"><img src=\"http://l-userpic.livejournal.com/119811849/13265658\" alt=\"\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"><br></div><a name=\"cutid1\"></a><br><br>Травка очень помогает при больных почках.<br>У вас болят почки?<br>-нет<br>-Жаль. Очень жаль.<br><br>***<br><br>профессия вождя - это точное соотнесение обещания и выполнения.<br><br>***<br><br>Есть порой у нас забота Отводить навет и ложь. Если стоишь ты чего-то, Без врагов не проживешь. Различать врагов не сложно; Так на свете повелось: Чем враги твои ничтожней, Тем безудержней их злость.<br><br>***<br><br>Чтобы не случилось—ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным<br><br>***<br>\"Great minds discuss ideas. Average minds discuss events. Small minds discuss people.\" - Elenanor Roosevelt <br>\"Великие умы обсуждают идеи. Средние умы обсуждают события. Низшие умы обсуждают людей.\" - Элеонор Рузвельт<br>***<br><br><br><br><a name=\"cutid1-end\"></a></div>"
```

I want to use this code, but these '\' signs appear everywhere.
I tried different types of gsubing, &q{ code } but it didn't help.

How I can do it?
Thanks

**ANSWER:**
I ve understood how to solve this.
Just do:

```
"<div class=\"user-icon\">".gsub("\"","'") => "<div class='user-icon'>"
```

Hope it will help anyone :)

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is not literally there. It is escaping the double quotation as there is no other way to distinguish them from the ones surrounding the whole string literal. You don't have to remove them; actually you can't because they are not there.